# Output existing wp_nav_menu with a custom walker

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

I am trying to output another wp_nav_menu if an existing wp_nav_menu item has a specific class like this..

```
/* Custom Walker */
class IBenic_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

// Displays start of an element. E.g '<li> Item Name'
// @see Walker::start_el()
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array(), $id = 0) {
    $object = $item->object;
    $type = $item->type;
    $title = $item->title;
    $description = $item->description;
    $permalink = $item->url;

    $output .= "<li class='" .  implode(" ", $item->classes) . "'>";
    $output .= '<a href="' . $permalink . '">';
    $output .= $title;
    $output .= '</a>';

    /* If Item Class Is shop_nav */
    if (in_array("shop_nav", $item->classes)) {
        $output .= '<ul class="sub-menu">
                        ' . wp_nav_menu( array(
                                'theme_location' => 'col_1',
                                'menu_id'        => 'col_1',
                                'menu_class'     => 'col_1',
                                'container'      => '',     
                                ) ) . '
                    </ul>';
    }

    $output .= '</li>';

}
}
```

This is not working as expected, can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By default [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) outputs the navigation markup. If you want to store it or want to concatenate it with other string then you'd have to set the `echo` parameter to `false` (by default it's `true`).

```
$output .= '<ul class="sub-menu">
        ' . wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'col_1',
                'menu_id'        => 'col_1',
                'menu_class'     => 'col_1',
                'container'      => '',
                'echo'           => false,
                ) ) . '
        </ul>';
```